# Fancybox - is it possible to use a javascript variable string as the HTML content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I know the instructions for Fancybox state that the content can be passed in any of four ways; Images, inline, iFrame or Ajax.

However I was wondering if I had a string like:

```
var html = "<p>Some html content</p>";
```

If I could invoke a a fancybox window using this content?

**EDIT** With regards to JFK's answer below, what is the best way to serve content depending on a condition? For example, let's say I have two different fancybox links:

```
<a href="#" class="fancybox class-one">Click me</a>
<a href="#" class="fancybox class-two">Click me</a>
```

So when either link is clicked, I want to display different content depending on the second class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can also set `html` as `type` of `content` so this should work

```
var html = "<p>Some html content</p>";
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "html", // not an image but html
        content: html // overrides fancybox content
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** that the API option `content` **overrides** the fancybox `content` regardless what is set in the `href` attribute of the anchor bound to fancybox so this

```
<a class="fancybox" href="images/01.jpg">Open Fancybox</a>
```

... will still display the value of the javascript variable in fancybox and not the image in the `href`

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d8mhzxn0/)**

---

**EDIT**:

To serve the content depending on the selector's *class* as in

```
<a href="#" class="fancybox class-one">Click me</a>
<a href="#" class="fancybox class-two">Click me</a>
```

... I think your best bet is to use a `switch` statement (inside the `.on()` method) to dynamically set the value of the `html` variable. Then launch fancybox programmatically like :

```
var html; // initialize variable globally
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").on("click", function () {
        switch (this.className) {
            case "fancybox class-one":
                html = "<p>Some html content for class-one</p>";
                break;
            case "fancybox class-two":
                html = "<p>And this the html content for class-two</p>";
                break;
            default:
                html = "<p>html default content</p>";
        };
        $.fancybox({
            type: "html",
            content: html
        });
        return false; 
    });
}); // ready
```

See forked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ppwd3pur/1)**

Comment: Hi, JFK, thanks for your answer- spot on. I actually have one further question on this topic which has just become apparent- please see the edit in my original question. Thanks.